# AWS beanstalk error every rime. We have a proc file, a package.json , and have zipped the the folder properly. Still this error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

this is the error we get --  ERROR    Instance deployment failed to generate a 'Procfile' for Node.js. Provide one of these files: 'package.json', 'server.js', or 'app.js'. The deployment failed.

made a proc file , remove gitignore too but no avail

Comment: could you double check if your package.json is in the root of your zip?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.